# I accidentally broke my local git repo. I've got it working again, but I still have a long list of dangling objects. Can an automated tool fix this?

Tags: git, macos

I've looked at the other similar questions here on SO, but I didn't find an answer that did what I'm hoping to do, and also some of the answers I didn't really understand.

Anyhow, I accidentally got my local repo completely broken. As in, many files in the `.git` folder no longer exist and so when I tried to open up the repo in [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) it couldn't load it. Almost all of my HEADS had an invalid sha1 pointer.

So what I did was, I got a clean clone from the origin and then I let Finder merge the `.git` folders of the clean clone and the broken repo.

The end result is that my git repo *does* work again, but when I run `git fsck` I have around 880 dangling objects (mostly blobs, and some commits and trees).

What I'm hoping for is that there might be a tool (or an already existing subcommand of git that I'm not familiar with), which is fully automated and does its best to re-integrate as many of those dangling objects into the working history. I understand that that may not be possible for all the dangling objects, but I'd already be happy if it can do 1.

Does such a tool exist? Otherwise, how would one go about this manually if one was really desperate.

### Edit

So to add some more information why this is important to me and why I don't just want to delete these dangling objects.

1. I had local branches with some experimental code that I hadn't pushed to remote yet. So origin does not have everything that I had locally. I would really like to get those branches back if possible.
2. I'm terrible at tracking my time while I'm working, because that's just not one of an ADHDer's strengths. So what I've been doing instead is that at the end of every month I look at `git log` and `git reflog` and I use that data to estimate how much I've worked every day of the month. So if I can't recover my branches, but I can save some dangling objects in the reflogs then I'd already be very happy.

Comment: Why not just clone and _don't_ Finder merge the folders?

Comment: *Dangling* commits, blobs, etc., are perfectly normal detritus left behind by doing work in a Git repository. They are harmless; `git gc` eventually cleans them out.

Comment: @matt Because I had local branches with some experimental code that I hadn't pushed to remote yet. So origin does not have everything that I had locally. I'm desperately hoping that I can recover some of those branches, even if I can only partly recover them. @torek I don't want to clean them out, see what I wrote to matt. And even if the dangling stuff can't be re-integrated into the working history, then I'd like to at least have them as ref-logs. Because at the end of every month, I estimate how many hours I have worked by looking at `git log` and `git reflog`. For me it's really vital info

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I was able to fix it as much as was possible. I've been able to reclaim most of my local branches. Here's how I got there:

I had a few different versions of the `.git` folder. The one that used to be my local working version and was now broken, which I had called `.git_broken`. Then I had `.git_clean_clone` from origin. And then I had two different versions of finder-merged folders,  which I called `.git_merged_left` and `.git_merged_right`.

All of them had different output when I ran `git fsck`. Some had errors and dangling objects and some had only dangling objects.

Then I found a tip somewhere on the internet that helped a great deal.

It was to create a file in `.git/objects/info` called `alternates` and it should contain absolute file paths to other versions of `.git/objects`. And then to run `$: git repack -a -d` in the terminal.

Well I did that trick a bunch of times, trying it with different versions as the base `.git` folder. Anyhow, it actually did something, in one of the versions it was able to figure out that a few dangling things were actually part of a commit that was part of one of my local branches.

I think I have most of my history back now and I'm very grateful for that.

Another tip I saw, which I also tried, but it didn't change anything for me after the repacking already fixed everything that could be fixed:

```bash
$: brew install git-annex
$: git annex repair
```